# jQuery Validate Plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery and jQuery Validate Plugin on a test page, my code is based on [validate demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/lib/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            submitHandler: function() { alert("submited!!!"); }
        });

        $().ready(function() {
            $("#registerForm").validate({
                rules : {
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlenght: 5
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlenght: 5,
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }
                },
                messages : {
                    username: {
                        required: "Please enter a username",
                        minlenght: "Your username must consist at least 2 characters"
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "Please enter a password ",
                        minlenght: "Your password must consist at least 5 characters"
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: "Please repeat the password",
                        minlenght: "Your password must consist at least 5 characters",
                        equalTo: "This password doesn't match with the original password"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Please enter a email",
                        email: "Invalid email"
                    }
                }
            });
        });    


    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #commentForm { width: 500px; }
        #commentForm label { width: 250px; }
        #commentForm label.error, #commentForm input.submit { margin-left: 253px; }
        #registerForm { width: 670px; }
        #registerForm label.error {
            margin-left: 10px;
            width: auto;
            display: inline;
            color: red;
        }
        #newsletter_topics label.error {
            display: none;
            margin-left: 103px;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body class="zoom: 1;">
    <div id="main">
    <form id="registerForm" method="post" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>OLA MUNDO</legend>
        <p><label for="username">Nome</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value=""></p>

        <p><label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value=""></p>

        <p><label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value=""></p>

        <p><label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
        <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" value=""></p>

        <p><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Enviar"></p>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</body>
```

The problem is that in my page the code doesn't work and i don't know why it happens.

I have a jquery.js file in my scripts directory but the script isn't loaded.
So i used the jquery from the demo site, i used the jquery hosted on google and that doesn't solves the problem. I don't know if the problem is on the script code, because i'm kind of newbie on javascript.

@Edit

I solved the problem but now the password and confirm password field doesn't validate, why? the js code is correct

Comment: Did you try to see the browser console if there are any script errors?

Comment: I see now, and it says **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ** and i solved!

Comment: Thanks guys it is solved, Hariprasad and nzn solved the problem

Comment: unexpected identifier -because of you missed the comma operator

Comment: Yeah, i solved that, but now the problem is other...

Answer (score 2):

you are writing your js before DOM is built up. Till then browser have not idea what register from is . So you have two option either put your javascript at bottom of page just above  tag or use window.onLoad function. This will work ...

Answer (score 1):

instead of `$("registerForm")` you should select by id `$("#registerForm")`

[jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I didn't saw that thanks, with that and what Hariprasad said solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you missed mention the selector id  `$("#registerForm")`and messages every method mention `,` operator

JS:

```
 $.validator.setDefaults({
            submitHandler: function() { alert("submited!!!"); }
        });

        $().ready(function() {
            $("#registerForm").validate({
                rules : {
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlenght: 5
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlenght: 5,
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }
                },
                messages : {
                    username: {
                        required: "Please enter a username",
                        minlenght: "Your username must consist at least 2 characters"
                    },   //missed comma
                    password: {
                        required: "Please enter a password ",
                        minlenght: "Your password must consist at least 5 characters"
                    },    //missed comma
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: "Please repeat the password",
                        minlenght: "Your password must consist at least 5 characters",
                        equalTo: "This password doesn't match with the original password"
                    },   //missed comma
                    email: {
                        required: "Please enter a email",
                        email: "Invalid email"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```